# Best way to handle OOME android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to set an image to an imageview in a custom dialog with a drawable. I have the following method

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.setCancelable(false);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
        image= (ImageView) vg.findViewById(R.id.image);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+this.getActivity().getPackageName()+"/drawable/p1");
        image.setImageURI(uri);
.
.
return builder.create();
}
```

It runs fine most of time but causes a Out of memory on a xxxx-byte allocation.

I know it is because of this

```
image.setImageURI(uri);
```

What is the best way to get rid of this problem??

UPDATE::

```
I tried to recycle the bitmap by using this 

Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        if(!bitmap.isRecycled()){
        bitmap.recycle();
        bitmap =null;
        }
```

Now If i get a dialong with same image consecutively I have this error:

```
Canvas trying to use a recycled bitmap Runtime Exception.
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to look into how much memory the app is using and where it's using it.  You're probably leaking somewhere.  If not, figure out how to reduce your overall memory usage.  Eclipse can get heap usage dumps for you.

Comment: Could you please tell me if I want to rescale and apply the image on the dialog efficiently?? or point me to some resource? THe dialog is called repeatedly and I am not using any static variables on the display to leak context. It just pops an image out and this OOME doesnt not happen always .. only rarely

Comment: It's not necessarily this dialog that's causing the problem.  It means the total memory usage by your app is too high.  It just happened to fail here.  You can't look at this dialog in isolation, you need to look at all memory use by the app.

Comment: Well, the UI of the activity is a button and textview and you get a pop out. The image from the drawable is 1280x720 image. So I am thinking that is causing the error. But the size of the image is 150 kB. I am frustrated enough already with debugging. I very much appreciate your patience in answering me.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse Memory Analyzer (http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) can help you find the leak, in conjunction with DDMS and the heap analyzer.

To start heap updates, you can switch to the DDMS view from within Eclipse, and in there you would select the process corresponding to your app, and then you would select the "Show heap updates" button. Then every time you click the "Cause GC" button you'll see an update of the objects on your heap.

To analyze this with Eclipse, you can then click the "Dump HPROF file" to load it with the Eclipse Memory Analyzer, which will give you more hints on what might be leaking.

This blog post on the Android developer's blog goes into a lot more detail: http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html